# rspec: test array of instances

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, testing, rspec

I'm trying to create rspec tests to test an array of instances. Specifically, I want to verify certain attributes of each instance within the array. Is there a way to use rspec to test this scenario?

For example, suppose I have the following array that I want to verify:

```
[#<Car id:1, buy_date: "2022-10-10", model: "Ford">, 
 #<Car id:2, buy_date: "2021-01-10", model: "Ferrari">, 
 #<Car id:3, buy_date: "2022-03-12", model: "Toyota">]
```

As my test, I want to check that the buy_date is correct. I tried the following expect statement but I don't think it's meant for arrays of instances so the tests failed when I expected them to pass.

```
expect(cars).to include([
                have_attributes(
                    buy_date: "2022-10-10"
                ),
                have_attributes(
                    buy_date: "2021-01-10"                   
                ),
                have_attributes(
                    buy_date: "2022-03-12"
                )
            ])
```

I've also tried it with `match_array` instead of `include` but the result was the same.

Any ideas how to use rspec to accomplish this?

Comment: What is `cars.first.buy_date.class`?

Comment: @mechnicov it's a string

Comment: If you use `match_array` instead of `include`, your test must be success. Is it real example? May be arrays sizes are different?

Comment: `match_array` indeed [should work](https://www.benpickles.com/articles/73-testing-an-array-of-objects-with-rspec-have_attributes)

Answer (score 0):

The [include](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/docs/built-in-matchers/include-matcher) matcher is meant to check if the tested collection contains the passed value. So you are checking if any of the elements in the `car` array is an array, containing 3 objects with the given attributes.

That's because you can have an array of arrays, and you should be able to test if a given array is contained as a value in the array of arrays.

To test multiple values, you have to pass them as multiple arguments:

```rb
expect(cars).to include(
                have_attributes(
                    buy_date: "2022-10-10"
                ),
                have_attributes(
                    buy_date: "2021-01-10"                   
                ),
                have_attributes(
                    buy_date: "2022-03-12"
                )
            )
```

To improve readability, RSpec offers multiple aliases:

```rb
expect(cars).to include(
                an_object_having_attributes(
                    buy_date: "2022-10-10"
                ),
                an_object_having_attributes(
                    buy_date: "2021-01-10"                   
                ),
                an_object_having_attributes(
                    buy_date: "2022-03-12"
                )
            )
```

Now the difference whether you will use `include` in this way, or `match_array` is whether you want to be permissive, e.g. allow `cars` to contains other elements as well, or you want it to `contain exactly` those ones.

Also, in terms of readability, I'd rather combine it with multiple matchers:

```rb
expect(cars).to
   include(an_object_having_attributes(buy_date: "2022-10-10"))
  .and include(an_object_having_attributes(buy_date: "2021-01-10"))
  .and include(an_object_having_attributes(buy_date: "2022-03-12"))
```